# Proof of the Addition of Hermitian Adjoints

Tags: proof-explanation, physics

I have been trying to work out a proof for the following statement using two linear operators A and B:
$$(A + B)^\dagger = A^\dagger + B^\dagger$$
using the following definition of a hermitian adjoint of an operator 
$$\langle \psi_1|A^\dagger|\psi_2\rangle = (\langle\psi_1|A|\psi_2\rangle)^*$$
where * denotes the complex conjugate, and $$\dagger$$ denotes the adjoint of the operator. 
I have worked out the property concerning the product of the above operators but their addition doesn't allow me to use the properties of the inner product as nicely?

Comment: Is $\langle\psi_1|(A+B)|\psi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_1|A|\psi_2\rangle+\langle\psi_1|B|\psi_2\rangle$?

Comment: Your inner product is linear in $A$ surely?

Comment: @R.Burton the operators are linear, so i would think this is true?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, but i cannot quite see how this mechanism would tie in the proof?

Comment: @DiracPretender: It follows from the first comment above. If $\langle \psi_1|C|\psi_2\rangle = \langle \psi_1|D|\psi_2\rangle$ for all $\psi_1,\psi_2$ then $C=D$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assumption:

$$\langle\psi_1|(A+B)|\psi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_1|A|\psi_2\rangle+\langle\psi_1|B|\psi_2\rangle\implies(\langle\psi_1|(A+B)|\psi_2\rangle)^*=(\langle\psi_1|A|\psi_2\rangle+\langle\psi_1|B|\psi_2\rangle)^*$$

By definition:

$$(\langle\psi_1|A|\psi_2\rangle+\langle\psi_1|B|\psi_2\rangle)^*=(\langle\psi_1|A|\psi_2\rangle)^*+(\langle\psi_1|B|\psi_2\rangle)^*$$

By transitivity of equality:

$$(\langle\psi_1|(A+B)|\psi_2\rangle)^*=(\langle\psi_1|A|\psi_2\rangle)^*+(\langle\psi_1|B|\psi_2\rangle)^*$$

Therefore:

$$\langle\psi_1|(A+B)^\dagger|\psi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_1|A^\dagger|\psi_2\rangle+\langle\psi_1|B^\dagger|\psi_2\rangle$$

Whence:

$$(A+B)^\dagger=A^\dagger+B^\dagger$$